Power button haptic feedback stopped working on MacBook Pro
The power button on my 13" 2020 MacBook Pro suddenly stopped vibrating when I tap on it.
Everything else works fine; just the  problem with haptic feedback.
Is there a fix for this?

That button has haptic feedback?  Weird, my 2020 didn't.  My 2021 M1 or my 2023 M2 either.

I haven't disassembled this particular model, but anything that provides haptic feedback means there's a mechanical "motor" (lack of a better word) that creates it.  If the button still functions otherwise and your only symptom is the haptic feedback is now missing, it means there's a physical problem with your key/button you need to replace it.  There's no setting or tweak you can modify that will enable it again.
However, (IMO) you should avoid this repair as you'll need to access the top case assembly and that requires nearly a full teardown of your Mac.  It's simply not worth the effort.  If you get to a point where you need to replace the battery, Apple recommends replacing the whole top case assembly which includes the component in question.
